# Exclude Specific Tag On Homepage

Tags: tags, exclude

I'd like to exclude Tag ID: 26 from my homepage. I've figured out how to do it with categories, but not with tags.

```
function exclude_posts( $query ) { 
if ( $query->is_home ) {  $query->set( 'cat', '-13' ); 
} } add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_posts' );
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
function exclude_posts( $query ) { 

    if ( $query->is_home() ) {  

        $query->set( 'tag__not_in', array( 13 ) ); 

    } 

} 

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_posts' );
```

`tag` and `tag_id` are not set up like `cat` to accept negative numbers (ID numbers) for exclusion (conclusion based on experiments, not digging into the code (some other time, perhaps!)). Also, all of the examples in the Codex use `is_home()`, `is_admin()`, etc., but apparently `is_home` does work - without the `()`.

Comment: Hi CK, your code worked. Thanks for sharing it as well as the explanation!

Comment: You're welcome, but please don't forget to mark my answer as good/accepted - as I close in on the magic 1000 mark!